# Get cline to cover space between column and previous column

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r||c|c||l}
Hello & test & run & done\\
\cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

###### Gives this output:

[image]

###### Hoped for output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the `tblr` environment from the `tabularray` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{r||c|c||l}
Hello & test & run & done\\
\cline{2-3}
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Edit: With multirow and colored cells (though don't look good to me).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{ninecolors}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {r||c|c||l},
    row{odd} = {gray9}
}
    Hello & test & run & done\\
    \cline{2-3}
    Hello & test & run & done\\
    \cline{2-3}
    \SetCell[r=2]{c} Hello & test & run & done\\
    \cline{2-3}
     & test & run & done\\
    \cline{2-3}
    Hello & test & run & done\\
    \cline{2-3}
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works in my actual table except for one error " \multicolumn is obsolete; use \SetCell instead.". Any tips how to replace `\multicolumn{2}{c||}{...}` also I had colored every second row... `\rowcolors{3}{ourgray}{}`

Comment: `tabularray` has stopped supporting `multicolumn` in a newer update. You need to change those by `\SetCell` command. Its usage is very easy. Format is `\SetCell[r=n]{alignment} content` where n is now of rows to span. You may take a quick look at the documentation. It has enough examples.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

That environment is similar to the classical environment `{tabular}` of `nicematrix` but also creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, rows and columns.

The, you can use those nodes with Tikz to draw whatever rule you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{r||c|c||l}
Hello & test & run & done \\
\CodeAfter \tikz \draw [shorten < = - \arrayrulewidth - \doublerulesep] (2-|2) -- (2-|4) ; 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because of the PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the first code]

If you prefer a more rustic solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r|@{}c|c||l}
Hello & \hspace{\doublerulesep}\vrule\hspace{\arraycolsep}test & run & done \\
\cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]

The junction of the rules is not perfect because `\cline` (for historical reasons), protrudes in the row below. It's possible to solve that problem by raising a bit the rule of the `\cline`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r|@{}c|c||l}
Hello & \hspace{\doublerulesep}\vrule\hspace{\arraycolsep}test & run & done \\[-\arrayrulewidth]
\cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the third code]

Comment: Thanks. Similar to Imran's solution it works great in the simple examples but destroys other aspects. Probably my example was too minimal.

Comment: You should provide a MWE for your (new) problem...